# Writing a csv where the lists aren't the same length

Tags: python, csv

I'm try to export `data` to csv, where the items in data are two lists of unequal length.

```
import csv

item_dictionary = {'13742': 'cat', '25037':'dog'}
names = item_dictionary.values()

data = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]

export_data = zip(*data)

myfile = open('sample.csv', 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(myfile)
wr.writerow(names)
wr.writerows(export_data)
myfile.close()
```

This gives me this output, which excludes the 5 and 6 in `data[0]`.

```
dog  cat
1    7
2    8
3    9
4    10
```

What I would  like is this:

```
dog  cat
1    7
2    8
3    9
4    10
5
6
```

How can I amend my code to include all values of `data[0]` without being limited by the length of `data[1]`?

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, `zip` stops which it reaches the end of the shortest iterable.
[itertools.izip_longest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) is the function to use when you want to zip to the end of the longest iterable.

```
import itertools
export_data = itertools.izip_longest(*data, fillvalue = '')
```